# Type error in wagmi's usePrepareContractWrite for value

Tags: typescript, wagmi, nextjs

I have next app with typescript and using wagmi (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wagmi) package to work with smart contracts. I am trying to prepare contract write using usePrepareContractWrite and need to send wei to the contract function. I included value (https://wagmi.sh/react/prepare-hooks/usePrepareContractWrite#value-optional) but getting a typescript error:

`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`

Here's how I constructed the function:

```
  const { config, error } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: contractAddress,
    abi,
    functionName: "purchaseProduce",
    args: [details?.farmer, details?.index],
    value: details?.price * details?.quantity,
  });
```

How can I fix this type error?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with you passing an undefined value in "value" field, or in "args", because you are using the "?" operator.

Run the code so that you are sure that you have these values.
Or using "enabled" mode in https://wagmi.sh/react/prepare-hooks/usePrepareContractWrite